# Transparent div with a glowing gradient border

Tags: css, reactjs, button, tailwind-css, styling

I'm trying to create a button with a glowing gradient border.

[image: I have this]

The problem is the button has to be transparent. Glow effect and custom gradient border are `<div>` elements behind the button, which is the only way I can think of to get this effect.

Would it be possible (and the best way to approach this) to have a `<div>` that's empty in the middle (where the button is) so, it becomes a border then I can stylize in a way that border property can't be?

This is my code right now, using Tailwind CSS:

```
<div className='grid gap-8 items-start justify-center mt-1.5'>
  <div className={`rounded-[8px] m-4 p-0.5 max-w-sm bg-gradient-to-tl from-gradient_2 to-gradient_2_2`}>
    <div className='relative group'>
      <div className={`absolute -inset-2 rounded-lg blur opacity-80  bg-gradient-to-tl from-gradient_2 to-gradient_2_2 group-hover:opacity-100 transition duration-500 group-hover:duration-200`}/>
      <button className={`rounded-[5px] relative px-7 py-2 bg-modal`}>
        <span className='text-text font-bold'>{label}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will probably have to use a `clip-path` or a `mask-image` for this.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/different-ways-to-get-css-gradient-shadows/

Comment: I tried to get this glowing button effect, and so far I got this result. I know it doesn't perfectly look like that but similar to that.  link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/7TXEURIvxm